# How can I get LuaLaTeX to turn three hyphens into an em-dash?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, punctuation

For some reason, LuaLaTeX is outputting an en-dash for both `--` and `---` for me.

MWE:

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}                                              

\begin{document}
blah-blah

blah--blah

blah---blah
\end{document}
```

`lualatex test` produces:

[image: LuaLaTeX output]

`pdflatex test` produces:

[image: PDFLaTeX output]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477094/35864

Comment: @moewe: That's exactly it, thank you. I was having a hard time figuring out search terms for this.

Comment: I can imagine that typing `---` into Google would not be helpful here ;-) (It is bad enough if you search for more recognisable code with a few more letters.) I only found the duplicate so quickly because I knew I had seen it before and could search in my browsing history for "em" and "Lua". Would you be OK with closing this as a duplicate?

Comment: The problem was a bug in the upstream fontloader involving ligatures and will be resolved with the next luaotfload update.