# LuaTeX and the minus / hyphen sign

Tags: luatex, punctuation, discretionary

In light of the  explanations given in [LuaTeX and em dashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477094/luatex-and-em-dashes)

"\automatichyphenmode=1 avoids the problem by not converting the hyphen to a discretionary in a number of cases."

and the LuaTeX Reference Manual  (8.2.7 disc nodes}

''The \discretionary and -, the - character but also the
hyphenation mechanism produces these nodes.''

I looked at the node lists in 4 diferent cases involving the hyphen/minus sign, using both \automatichyphenmode=1 and \automatichyphenmode=0

[image]

The correct expected behavior (after the bug is fixed) will be that the glyph char 45 [-] nodes in the 4 cases will be produced as  disc (automatic) nodes?
(that is, mode=node (0) behavior will also be modified? glyph char 45 ==> disc in both columns?)

This a very very basic code. The output will match the table.

---

\automatichyphenmode=1

Glyph

Glyph ; Glyph

Glyph ; Glyph

Glyph ; Disc > Subtype 2 ; Glyph

---

\automatichyphenmode=0

Glyph

Glyph ; Glyph

Disc > Subtype 2 ; Glyph

Glyph ; Disc > Subtype 2; Glyph

---

```
    % !TeX TS-program = lualatex

    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \directlua{
    show_dash = function(head)
    while head do
      if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then % hlist, vlist
             texio.write_nl(" ")
              show_dash(head.head)
      elseif head.id == 7 then             % disc
        texio.write_nl("Disc > Subtype " .. head.subtype)
      elseif head.id == 29 then             % glyph
        texio.write_nl("Glyph ")
      end
     head = head.next
    end 

   end
     luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",show_dash,"show_dash")
      }


  \begin{document}
   \begin{minipage}{20pt}
      \automatichyphenmode=1    % good for en dash and em dash      
          -

          A-

          -B

          A-B
    \end{minipage}

   \begin{minipage}{20pt}
      \automatichyphenmode=0        
             -

            A-

           -B

           A-B
   \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add some code I can test - I have the fix already locally.

Comment: @Mico I would like to know if the fix for the ''en'' and ''em'' dashes bug will change  both the mode=base and mode=node, in order to match the Ref Manual.

I started \automatichyphenmode=1 as recommend, but it looks that this setting not önly "this suppress line breaking in a number of cases" but has other effects as well.

Up to now the incorrect node generation does not have any consequenses, but it could, at a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your test file is with tl19 and the next luaotfload version for `automatichyphenmode=1` is:

```
Glyph 

Glyph 
Glyph 

Glyph 
Glyph 

Glyph 
Disk > Subtype 2
Glyph
```

with `automatichyphenmode=0` I get:

```
Glyph 

Glyph 
Glyph 

Disk > Subtype 2
Glyph 

Glyph 
Disk > Subtype 2
Glyph
```

This is imho identical to your table, and it is also the expected result. The hyphen is only converted to a discretionary if is is between glyphs (both cases) or before a glyph (0).

The fix you mentioned doesn't change anything here. It only resolves a problem with ligatures consisting of three chars (which affected `---` to).

Comment: I do not see why it is "the expected result"  nor why they are different.


What do you make of the sentence in LuaTeX Reference Manual (8.2.7 disc nodes}?


''The \discretionary and -, the - character but also the hyphenation mechanism produces these nodes.''


I expected to get (always)


Disc > Subtype 2


Glyph 
Disc > Subtype 2


Disc > Subtype 2
Glyph 


Glyph 
Disc > Subtype 2
Glyph 


By the way,  the hyphenation mechanism produces Disc > Subtype 3  which is fine imho.

Comment: You don't always want the hyphen to be a discretionary. E.g. as a german I don't want a breakpoint after the hyphen  in `-saft`. For me the behaviour is sensible, if you want something else you should make a feature request at the luatex mailing list.

Comment: I agree with you, this is the  sensible behaviour. Perhaps the wording of the Manual is not explicit enough.
I am going to accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: The wording of the documentation is in many places unclear (and sometimes even wrong).